# What should I type in flat list to fetch that json API, I got the response and I can consol.log it

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, axios

I try to fetch data from Firebase with Axios and Redux to handle the state, Everything Is fine and I could console.log the data too, but FlatList doesn't show any data, Here is my Code:

Here is the Action of Redux.

```
import axios from "axios";
import {  GET_PRODUCTS } from "./types";

export const fetchData = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return axios
      .get("https://learn-efc13-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/products.json")
      .then((response) => {
        return response.data;
      })
      .then((data) => {
        dispatch({
          type: GET_PRODUCTS,
          payload: data,
        });
        console.log(data);
      })

      .catch((error) => {
        throw error;
      });
  };
};
```

Here is the reducer

```
import { GET_PRODUCTS } from "./types";

const initState = {
  availableProducts: [],
};

const reducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_PRODUCTS:
      return {
        availableProducts: action.availableProducts,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default reducer;
```

And finally, the Screen, That contains the FlatList

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Text, FlatList } from "react-native";

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { fetchData } from "./store/action";

function ScreenMain() {
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchData());
  }, [dispatch]);

  const data = useSelector((state) => state.availableProducts);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <View style={styles.con}>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Text>
            {item.name}
            {item.age}
          </Text>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

export default ScreenMain;
```

I Added the useEffect hook to console.log data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you wrap the `<FlatList />` like this:

```
{data && 
  <FlatList
     data={data}
     keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
     renderItem={({ item }) => (
       <Text>
         {item.name}
         {item.age}
       </Text>
     )}
 />}
```